# New MacBook Pro not detecting external Samsung monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I bought a new MacBook Pro 14" M1 Max to replace my older one. My older MacBook could connect to a wide Samsung monitor just fine when the new MacBook could not even detect the external display.

Since it is probably not a cable problem, what else could it be?

Comment: If the monitor is connected via USB-C, try flipping the connector on the MBP. While USB-C is supposed to work whichever way it's connected, users have noticed that some cables won't work in certain orientations. I have a cable like that.

Answer (score 2):

Even though you think it is not a cable problem, it might still very well be a cable problem.

I would advise trying with a different cable. Preferably a quality one.